# sys.dm_exec_requests and cpu_time

Tags: dmv

If a query is executing on a multi-core server, and the query uses parallel threads, will `sys.dm_exec_requests.cpu_time`show the cpu time consumed by all threads executing the query? I assume this is the case, but I can't find documentation indicating this.

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

Elapsed time usually shows how long the request was running for, and CPU - a cumulative time of all processes. For example,  I usually see CPU x4 times higher than the elapsed time when the request's DOP is 4. When DOP is 1, then elapsed time matches CPU time.